# Use random functions (Python turtle graphics)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm working with the turtle module in Python, and I want to use a random function to go left, right, forward...  My code is:

```py
from turtle import *
from random import randint, choice

speed(0)

#Lists and variables
turtles = []

for i in range(20):
    turtles.append(Turtle())

while 1:
    for i in turtles:
        print(choice([i.left(90),i.right(90),i.forward(100),i.backward(100)]))
```

My problem is all four functions are executed, like if my code was this:

```py
... 

while 1:
    for i in turtles:
        i.left(90)
        i.right(90)
        i.forward(100)
        i.backward(100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're choosing from the results of all the method calls (which all return `None`) rather than choosing one method and then calling it.  Instead try:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from random import choice

# Lists and variables
turtles = []

for _ in range(20):
    tortoise = Turtle()
    tortoise.speed('fastest')
    turtles.append(tortoise)

while True:
    for tortoise in turtles:
            (choice([tortoise.left, tortoise.right, tortoise.forward, tortoise.backward]))(90)
```

[image]